# register_globals off - now I get an odd undefined but it shouldn't be

Tags: php, global-variables, undefined-index, register-globals

**What I had BEFORE was...**

```
if(DEBUGMODE) $debug_err_msgs[] = 'Some error'; // add a new error to the array

... more code here...

if(DEBUGMODE)$debug_err_msgs[] = 'Some error'; // add a new error to the array
```

which worked great EXCEPT in functions.  SO... I decided to make it GLOBAL by using the $_GLOBALS array.  I originally liked the 1st method I chose because it kept adding to the array and I could dump it later on to view what was happening..  Using the `$_GLOBALS['debug_err_msgs']` and `$_GLOBALS['errorh_string']` is forcing me to `.=` (append) the string to the previous one (which is ok... I didn't think you could go... `$_GLOBALS['something'][]` and keep adding to the array like I did before I changed my code.  SO.. I made changes as below...

**PHP**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");

$_GLOBALS['errorh_string'] = "";
if(DEBUGMODE) $_GLOBALS['debug_err_msgs'] = "";
if(DEBUGMODE) $_GLOBALS['debug_err_msgs'] .= 'La la la, some errors';
if(DEBUGMODE) $_GLOBALS['debug_err_msgs'] .= 'more errors... etc';

function ErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    // if ($errno == 8) return;// 8 is undefined variables
    $error = "<b>Error[</b>$errno<b>] </b>$errstr<br />";
    $_GLOBALS['errorh_string'] .= $error; // append new error to the global string
    return true;    // dont execute the php internal error handler
}
?>
```

**ERRORS IM GETTING**

Notice: Undefined index: errorh_string in /debugOpenBlock.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: errorh_string in /debugOpenBlock.php on line 14

Which in the code above, is INSIDE the function

```
$_GLOBALS['errorh_string'] .= $error; // GIVES ME UNDEFINED
```

Here is what's weird... if I change the line to read...

```
$_GLOBALS['errorh_string'] = $error; // NO ERROR NOW
```

I even tried

```
$_GLOBALS['errorh_string'] = $_GLOBALS['errorh_string'] . $error; // GIVES ME UNDEFINED
```

***If `'errorh_string'` is a literal? why do I get undefined in it.!?!??!  Am I missing something about GLOBALS?***

*As I was writting this I was thinking I could have used*

```
global $debug_err_msg[]; // make this array global
```

instead of changing all my code to the way I have it now but... I'm curious what this problem is now...  I hate not knowing something :)

BTW - I just recently turned off register_globals in the PHP.INI file.  Could this have anything to do with it (note: I NEVER used $_SESSION['somevariable'] as $somevariable (mainly because I didn't know you could do that but... doesn't matter anyways)).

I've read piles of articles about superglobals, register_globals etc but nothing sheds any light on this..

*Awaiting wisdom oh greater than I web developers :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find another problem, so the issue seems that you just used the wrong variable name. It is called [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/GLOBALS), not `$_GLOBALS` - unlike the input arrays. (It's not affected by the register_globals setting btw.)

```
 global $debug_err_msg;
```

You should actually prefer this method. That makes using the variable more legible than with the `$GLOBALS[]` access, and it also shows that you intentionally share that variable.

Comment: OH MY!!!    I didnt even notice that $_GLOBALS vs $GLOBALS.  LOL!   Very silly mistake I made.   I'll try it out and see if that's it... (I'm sure it is).  And I agree - global is better.  I wish I had of seen THAT method before I changed about 80 lines of code :) lol.

One question... I read that you have to use

global $debug_err_msg; everywhere.  Is that true?  Or can I define it as a global once and just use $debug... elsewhere?

Comment: No, you do have to explicitly "invite" it into each local scope. (PHP hasn't real global variables as other languages). Might be a bit more typing, but makes it super explicit. But you can of coure mix and match the two approaches. Use `$GLOBALS[..]` where you need that variable only once e.g.

Comment: That was it!   Much appreciated!   It was bad of me to assume that all PHP's super globals started with $_  :(  But, lesson learned!!!  I'll change it from $GLOBALS[''] to globals.  I have a feeling I can go back to the way I had it before...   


global $more[] = 'more errors added to the array';

which I liked better than appending.

It's nice when the token highlights!  I didn't even notice that either :)  $_GLOBALS stays black in Dreamweaver - $GLOBALS and global light up :) lol

Comment: .. and for legibility... i would rather supply global before the variable anyways to "pull" it into scope.   Clearer for when I come back in 5 years and forget all about it :)  Thx for the clarification!

Comment: ooo... I just tried doing global $string = ""; - it appears as if I have to bring it into scope and THEN use it... not all in 1 step.  I'll look into it more...

Comment: Yes, the global statement is restrictive about that. It only allows importing base variable names, no assignment expressions. So that might occasionally be one of the other reasons to resort to the `$GLOBALS` alias.

Comment: I changed them all to $GLOBALS[''] since for what I'm doing - it's the easier of the 2.  I try never to use globals but for building an error string as the program weaves in and out of functions and files - this works wonderfully!  Thank you for your input!  Much appreciated!  My website is once again humming along!  I also noticed that my error handler is working BETTER than before - so, I'm happy about that.  I have a feeling it wasn't `.=`'ing stuff properly due to scope (that I missed before).  Now, instead of blank pages I get error msgs!  YAY!  Off to code :)